# IF statement with current time Function in Xpath

Tags: xpath, infopath

I have a Text box Infopath that displays the current time using this function:

(substring-after(now(), "T")

I also have a Drop-Down list called "Location" that has the following values:

1.Boston

2.India

3.London

I want to modify this function to set the current time to always display the current time in Boston whether the user is from India or London.

I believe that inputting an If Statement that follows these conditions:

1. If **Location** (Drop down list) = "**London**" - Then use (substring-after(now(), "T") **subtracted** by **5 hours**.
2. If **Location** (Drop down list) = "**India**" - Then use (substring-after(now(), "T") **subtracted** by **11 hours**.
3. If **Location** (Drop down list) = "**Boston**" - Then use (substring-after(now(), "T").

I'm relatively new to Xpath and require assistance.

Comment: Infopath only uses XPath 1.0 and there is no standard function in XPath 1.0 that produces the current time.

Comment: But the function im using is working. It generates the current time thats listed on your computer. I just open the text box, click on the function icon and then input the current time function and it works. Isn't that Xpath?

Comment: user1886492, XPath 1.0 doesn't have a function that returns the current time this is some kind of extension function (or not XPAth at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to subtract the hours before ripping the time off the end with substring.

```
substring-after(addSeconds(now(), -3600 * 5), "T")
```

WARNING: Remember the current time (`now()`) is calculated from the LOCAL machine. So if a person in London opens the form they will already be at London time and then your code will subtract 5 hours on top of that - making it incorrect.